# EEG data classification in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have EEG data files which I want to classify into 2 classes using tensorflow in CNN.My data is 3D(91,2500,39),91 is the no of electrode,2500 no of samples and 39 is the number of chunks.The last dimension(39) varies in different files between(38-41),So after reducing the dimension to 2D I resize all the files to (91,97500) and append all the files to my empty list with the following codes

```
 for file in os.listdir(dataDir):
    data=scipy.io.loadmat(file)
    x=data['eegdata']
    x = x.reshape(91, -1)
    x=cv2.resize(x,(91,97500))
    # x=x.reshape(8872500)
    # print(x.shape)
    X.append(x)
X=np.array(X)
```

I then created tensor placeholder for my input raw data with dimension [None,8872500],the value 8872500 comes from 91*97500,I am supposed to classify the data into two classes

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 8872500])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

I reshaped my input before feeding to my convolution layer

```
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 91, 97500, 1])
```

my batch size is 6,when I run my codes I get an error

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (6, 97500, 91) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 8872500)'

I tried to reshape my input to 8872500(as it can be seen on the commented part of the for loop),when I do that my computer stack,which shapes should I use for my program(tensor and input)?
My Session looks like this

```
    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1

    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (ytrain.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_x = xtrain[offset:(offset + batch_size)]
        batch_y = ytrain[offset:(offset + batch_size)]


        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: dropout})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you got good results? I was researching about how to classify eeg data and according to other posts, cnn is not good and results will be terrible and recommend to use deep nn instead.

Comment: Yes I got good results,it was a two class problem,we got 99% classification accuracy. I used the same model on another 64 channels EEG and I got 96% classification accuracy(five classes problem)@PabloGonzalez

Comment: I see. I am trying with dnn but I cannot get that high accuracy so maybe I should try with cnn. Let me know if you know a good online reference for eeg classification using cnn. I followed some comments and people said dnn is the right way to do that but your results prove that cnn can do a good job too.

Comment: Personally I didnt get any online reference for EEG classification using CNN, I have been asking here for exact points where I was stacking. So may be if you stack you can ask here and you can get help as it was with me or you can rich me personally@PabloGonzalez

Comment: This paper might give you a breakthrough  http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5492691 @PabloGonzalez

Comment: Thank you @dm5 for your reference. Right now, I am trying to figure out how to input the eeg raw data into the cnn in order to get good results and respect the spatio-temporal shape. I have been reading several papers and most of them recommend to create a 2D spectrogram and input these spectrograms as images to the cnn. Using dataset from this paper http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0135697 , I will create a electrode number value vs time matrix for each trial (spectrogram image), i.e. based on this paper, 124x32. Btw, how do you recommend to input?

Comment: That is right,keep your input as 2D(number of electrodes(channels),length of the signal as you want). In my two projects I used 128(as the number of channels) then I sliced the input with a moving window of 100 length. In another project my input was 64,50 as 64 the number of channels and 50 as the length of my moving window. In both two projects I achieved good results. So,keeping the input in 2D is a good approach.@PabloGonzalez

Comment: I finally completed my cnn but results were not as good as expected. My input is 124 channels x 32 time sample (3968 eeg raw data points per trial). However, using a sequence: conv1 (5x5@32), pool1(2x2), conv2(5x5@32), pool2(2x2), conv3 (5x5@64), pool3 (2x2), flat (3840), dense (1024),dropout (0.5), logits(final categories:6), I just can get accuracy of 0.25. Very disappointing. Any feedback about my cnn structure or maybe a reason why my results are not too good?

Comment: To me,your network looks fine although most of the time I use only two convolution, two pooling layers and one or two fully connected layers. You can also try different window sizes.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your feedback. I will keep trying with different window size. My first attempt was using 2 conv and 2 pool as examples but accuracy was low. Since then, I have been doing modifications in the structure but without getting any better results. Maybe, my data is not the best and the output are 6 classes what make the classification problem more complicated to solve. Do you have any recommendation of a good and clean eeg dataset to use for testing?

Comment: I am about to publish a paper, I will be comfortable to share my data with you after my publication@PabloGonzalez

Comment: Let me know when your paper is published. I will be happy to read it and give you a feedback. Send me a private message or write below or contact me by email: blopag24@hotmail.com

Comment: I will contact you@PabloGonzalez

Comment: did you publish your work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the shape of batch_x? The problem is with your placeholder: 
Try this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 91, 97500])
```

Also, it would be better to call the variable after reshaping x something like `reshaped_x` to prevent confusion.

Comment: The shape of batch_X is [6,91,97500],My computer stack/freeze When I use x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 91, 97500]),I have the same problem when I reshape my X  ie x=x.reshape(8872500).With these two trials I dont have a shape error message but freezing of my computer until I manualy restart.I tried to use gc.collect() to clear memory but still freezing@rmeertens

Comment: This solution worked after changing the parameters of my convolution and pooling layer.My computer was stacking due to the large size of the input data after the pooling.